Regret bound of epsilon-greedy algorithm for multi-armed bandit problem
Consider $1$-subgaussian MAB with $n\geq 2$, consider the $\epsilon$-greedy algorithm: First choose each arm once and subsequently choose $A_t=\arg\max \hat \mu_i(t-1)$ with pr. $1-\epsilon_t$ and otherwise choose an arm uniformly at random.
We want to prove that, assume $\Delta_{\min}=\min\{\Delta_i:\Delta_i>0\}$,where $\Delta_i= \max \mu_j-\mu_i$, and let $\epsilon_t=\min\{1,\frac{Cn}{t\Delta_{\min}^2}\}$, where $C$ is a sufficiently large universal constant, prove there exists $C’>0$ universal s.t.
$$R_T\leq C'\sum_{i=1}^n(\Delta_i+\frac{\Delta_i}{\Delta_{\min}}\log\max\{e,\frac{T\Delta_{\min}^2}{n}\}).$$
My idea is to analyse every arm's regret respectively, i.e., the expectation of numbers that arm $i$ are chosen, and partition it into exploration part and exploitation part, in the first part every arm has chance to be chosen with pr. $\epsilon_t/n$, and in the exploitation part, we can choose a time threshold $t$ s.t. when $T>t$, suboptimal arms will be choosen with a sufficiently small probability. However, I don't know how to chooce proper way to reach the result same as this problem.
